# Javascript: Sum objects in a collection

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a way to consolidate a collection of objects in javascript.
For example I have a collection:

```
inventory = [ 
    {count: 1, type: "Apple"},
    {count: 2, type: "Orange"},
    {count: 1, type: "Berry"},
    {count: 2, type: "Orange"},
    {count: 3, type: "Berry"}
]
```

What I want to end up with is:

```
   inventory = [
        {count: 1, type: "Apple"},
        {count: 4, type: "Orange"},
        {count: 4, type: "Berry"}
     ]
```

Is there an elegant way to do this that doesn't involve getting a list of types, searching through my collection for those types, summing the values, and making a new array with the sums?

Comment: where are you getting this information? via a database? perhaps it would be better to aggregate natively rather than in JS.

Comment: I am getting this data through running regex on a list of strings, so unfortunately unable to aggregate before I get to the JS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not overly pretty, but this will do it. It creates both a dictionary of item types/counts, and a list of the final sums. `inventoryDict` is used to easily find the existing count, while `summedInventory` holds the final list of summed items.

```
var inventory = [ /* ... */ ];
var summedInventory = [];
var inventoryDict = {};

for (var i = 0; i < inventory.length; i++) {
    var item = inventory[i];
    if (!(item.type in inventoryDict)) {
        inventoryDict[item.type] = {type: item.type, count: 0};
        summedInventory.push(inventoryDict[item.type]);
    }
    inventoryDict[item.type].count += item.count;
}
```

This is is assuming that you do not want to mutate the inventory items in place - the loop can be slightly simplified if you do not mind mutating the items.

To avoid the intermediate variable and do it in a more functional manner, you could use Array.reduce:

```
var newInventory = inventory.reduce(function(acc, item) {
    var summedInventory = acc[0], inventoryDict = acc[1];

    if (!(item.type in inventoryDict)) {
        inventoryDict[item.type] = {type: item.type, count: 0};
        summedInventory.push(inventoryDict[item.type]);
    }

    inventoryDict[item.type].count += item.count;
    return acc;
}, [[], {}])[0];
```

Comment: Did you test this? I thought the format would be `item['type']` and `item['count']`

Comment: +1 for reduce solution which is a bit more intuitive IMO, albeit not as compatible.

Comment: @Zeaklous JavaScript allows you to use either `obj.name` or `obj['name']`. They are equivalent. When the property you are looking up is a valid identifier and known at the time of writing, the preferred option is usually `obj.name`. The other variant is useful for keys only known at run time, or for keys that are not valid identifiers: `keyName = "hello"; obj[keyName]` and `obj['name with spaces'];`

Comment: Right, right. Had to brush up on my jQuery formatting. All is good!

Answer (score 1):

My solution is this:

```
inventory = [ 
    {count: 1, type: "Apple"},
    {count: 2, type: "Orange"},
    {count: 1, type: "Berry"},
    {count: 2, type: "Orange"},
    {count: 3, type: "Berry"}
];

result = {};
inventory.map(function(item) {
    console.log(item);
    var count = result[item.type] || 0;
    result[item.type] = item.count + count;
});

inventory = [];

for (property in result) {
    inventory.push({count: result[property], type: property});
}

console.log(inventory);
```

See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/saeedneamati/B9L36/).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a relatively slim way of doing it using Javascript's [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2FReduce):

```
var reduced = inventory
    .reduce(function(sum,current) {
        var found = false
        sum.forEach(function(row,i) {
            if (row.type === current.type) {
                sum[i].count += current.count
                found = true;
            }
        })
        if (found === false) sum.push(current)
        return sum
    }, [])

console.log(reduced)
```